# Texture Exporting Problem

Tags: texturing

I have the Problem, that when I export my project as Fbx, the Textures don't come with it. I tried changing the Method used to reference paths to copy and activate embed Textures but it didn't work. I also tried to unpack all into files but nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Do you have any procedural textures (nodes)?

If so, bake them to image textures. Lot's of stuff about baking on YouTube.

#### 2. What is your aim with exporting it?

Is there some way of importing those textures into where ever you want the model?
If so, the UV's should be there whether or not the textures are.

#### 3. Are there any other formats that you could use?

#### 4. Relative paths?

Have you tried moving your textures into the same folder as your blender file, but not packing it all into the blend file?

#### 5. And of course restarting Blender.